# How to select a paragraph that contains a floating image?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'd like to be able to write a CSS rule that applies to a paragraph, but only if that paragraph contains an `<img>` tag with an `align` attribute. Note I do not want to select the image, but the paragraph that contains it. (I want to apply the style `clear: both` to the paragraph to make sure there is room for the floating image in the margin.) Is this possible using only CSS rules supported by current browsers?

Currently I'm actually munging the HTML generated by a help tool using a post-processing script I wrote, but doing it with CSS would be far more elegant and less trouble-prone.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this with CSS, you may need jquery.

Comment: Guess I'll keep doing it with the post-processing, then.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS doesn't have any parent selectors, only descendant.  You would have to use javascript to select the img tag and then call getParent() on it.

in Mootools javascript library:

```
$('p img[align=*]').getParent();
```

See Also:

CSS selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

Comment: That's pretty succinct compared to the jQuery version. If I decide to use a JavaScript library for this (that's problematic given that these will be local files, and Chrome has some restrictions on JavaScript in local files) it looks like this is the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: JQuery also implements of all the CSS3 selectors as well. The jquery syntax might look like this: `jquery('p img[align=*]').parent()` http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 0):

There are no CSS selectors that allow you to do this (what is essentially a look-behind selection). The best options you have for cross-browser support would be:

1. Adding JS to your page to detect the floated image, and then apply a css class to the parent paragraph.
2. Modify the code in place (if at all possible) to add a css class to the parent paragraph for any floated images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The idea of support for a 'contains' attribute has been dropped, as browsers don't support selecting parents of the selector.

It would be fairly easy to do this in jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/2u7fg/1/

```
$('p').each(function() {
     if ($(this).find('img').attr('align').length)
         $(this).css('background', 'red');
});
```

EDIT: hopefully less verbose version (I'm sure there's a better way of doing this)...

```
$('img').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('align').length > 0; }).parent().css('background', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2u7fg/2/